# NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields case sensitivity

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value-observing

How come that `-[[NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields] valueForKey:]` is case insensitive, while `valueForKey:` for manually created `NSDictionary` is not?

Both seems to be instances of `NSCFDictionary`;

Poking the first one with variation of, let's say, `Content-Type`, `content-type`, `ConTEnt-TYPe` returns the same value

Manually created `NSDictionary *a = @{ @"content-type" : @"pillows" }` returns `nil` for any spelling other then lowercase "content-type"

**Edit** Turns out this behavior can be easily achieved when dropping down to core foundation level: https://gist.github.com/steipete/7739473

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't both NSCFDictionary

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields];
    NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[dictionary1 allValues] forKeys:[dictionary1 allKeys]];
}
```

in lldb:

```
(lldb) po [dictionary2 class]
__NSDictionaryI
(lldb) po [dictionary1 class]
__NSCFDictionary
```

and seems __NSCFDictionary keys are actually case-insensitive 0_0.
Class inheritance looks so for __NSCFDictionary:
__NSCFDictinary <-- NSMutableDictionary <-- NSDictionary.
For __NSDictionaryI:
__NSDictionaryI <-- NSDictionary
Check debug output:

```
(lldb) po [dictionary1 superclass]
NSMutableDictionary
(lldb) po [[dictionary1 superclass] superclass]
NSDictionary
(lldb) po [dictionary2 superclass]
NSDictionary
```

I also created

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary3 = [dictionary2 mutableCopy];
```

and tried

```
(lldb) po [dictionary3 class]
__NSDictionaryM
(lldb) po [[dictionary3 class] superclass]
NSMutableDictionary
(lldb) po [[[dictionary3 class] superclass] superclass]
NSDictionary
(lldb) po dictionary3[@"date"]
 nil
(lldb) po dictionary3[@"Date"]
Sun, 01 Dec 2013 13:35:22 GMT
```

So it seems like only __NSCFDictionary subclass of NSMutableDictionary has case-insensitive keys.
And.. i think it's made through `-objectForKey:` `-setObject:forKey:` implementation. Not through custom NSString's.
Moreover, this `__NSCFDictionary` is immutable subclass of NSMutableDictionary.. it overrides `setObject:forKey:` to throw exception.
**So the short answer is:**
It's done by Apple through some private Foundation dictionary class.

Comment: @Daij-Djan i misspelled, you're right. EDIT. no, i was actually right - __NSDictionaryI is case-sensitive, __NSCFDictionary is case-insensitive

Comment: then the classnames are misleading ;) but a normal dict is not in any case

Comment: they could use custom NSString objects that have isEqual be case insensitive

Comment: That is strange – I'm testing it on simulator of 7.0 using `AFNetworking` (which hardly seems to be the issue) and it shows `__NSCFDictionary` for both cases

Comment: this answer is as useless as mine :D - implementation details. a for efort though :D

Comment: this not valid for systems.. NSCFDict is no subclass of the NSMutableDict .. it is all one class cluster AFAIK

Comment: Okay. I am testing it on OS X 10.8 using NSURLConnection delegate. And the debug output is shown above. If you `po` your dicts in another system and the result differs - please, show it. I think this should be same through all versions of Foundation framework, both iOS and OS X. And, @AlexanderZats, instances of same class cannot behave differently, i'm sure. Probably you misspelled somewhere.